# Is there any evidence that 40k lifted these races from Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, warhammer-40k

Been curious for a while. There are certainly some differences in the details, but at surface there seem to be parallel to me between Eldar and Vulcans, Dark Eldar and Romulans.

They're both basically analogues to light/dark elves, but additionally there's the psychic connection, the depth of feels and suppression of same by the "light" version, embracing violence and slavery by the "dark" version, and so on.

Obviously the 40k versions are somewhat more extreme in a lot of ways, but 40k tends to lay on tropes like a hammer in any case, making anything a more extreme version of the source material.

I guess I'm looking for any evidence for or against the idea that the 40k designers drew inspiration from Trek, whether in notes, interviews, blog posts, etc.

Comment: Warhammer Fantasy seemed to already have pretty lengthy lore surrounding High Elf and Dark Elf races, and they had armies in that tabletop game.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about Eldar and Dark Eldar, though, which is quite the same.  For example, High Elves have no concept of suppressing emotion like  Eldar and Vulcans do  The high and dark elf races of Fantasy are pretty well grounded in a mix of Tolkien and mythological sources.

Comment: pretty much everything in WH (FB and 40k) is basically GW's "take" on another source.

Comment: Wow, a -2 so far.  Anyone feel like telling me how to improve the quality? I thought it was pretty clear and on topic

Comment: people like to throw hate...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short: not really

The Eldar and Dark Eldar in the 40k universe are lifts from the original Wahammer Elves and [Dark Elves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Elves_(Warhammer))
 (other races brought across were Chaos, the Empire, Orks, Dwarves/Squats, Halflings/Ratlings, among others).

Dark Elves actually come from Norse mythology - although the Warhammer Dark Elves are quite different from the mythical creatures (as are the Elves). Dark Elves were originally called Night Elves in the 1983 first edition.

And while there was an allusion to a possible shared heritage of the Vulcan and Romulan races in Star Trek: TOS - the Romulans only appeared a handful of times in TOS and the relationship was only made official in TNG season 5's Unification which aired in 1991.

Comment: And no inquisitors to keep the federation in line?! #not in my imperium

Comment: Yah, if anything, 40ks underlying fluff is more of a space conversion of common fantasy tropes: Tolkien + Moorcock with lasers. :)